Ubuntu 24.04 LTS supplied snap "core22" has file without correctly assigned group
I spun up the latest AWS release of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and "/snap/core22/1722/usr/bin/ssh-agent" is assigned to an "UNKNOWN" group 118.  I am attempting to follow security best practice and ensure all files have a correct group assignment.  In previous releases I have found that this file is assigned to group "lxd".  Is this an error or expected?  Any insight greatly appreciated.
File in unknown group (current AWS release)
root@ip-10-0-100-7:/snap/core22/1722/usr/bin# stat ssh-agent
  File: ssh-agent
  Size: 293304          Blocks: 573        IO Block: 1024   regular file
Device: 7,0     Inode: 1193        Links: 1
Access: (2755/-rwxr-sr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  118/ UNKNOWN)

Showing file in lxd group (previous AWS release)
root@ip-10-0-6-164:/snap/core18/2829/usr/bin# stat ssh-agent
  File: ssh-agent
  Size: 362640          Blocks: 709        IO Block: 1024   regular file
Device: 7,1     Inode: 1970        Links: 1
Access: (2755/-rwxr-sr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  105/     lxd)


The assigned is the same in Core 22 installed in a WSL, so at least it is not specific for the Ubuntu installation on AWS. In Core 20 (rev2434) the group is 105/messagebus.
As snaps are in a Read-Only SquashFS filesystem you cannot change the user / group anyway.

Seems like a bug -- file it on launchpad using apport-bug. 118 is assigned to pipewire on my system.

@noisefloor thanks for the info.  I'm just trying to avoid a policy exception.  Read only or not I have to account for it unfortunately.

@ubfan1 thanks, i will report.
